# @model,ViewBag does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Please , i am having an issue with my View, I am using VS 2013 Express and building mv4 web app. For the first time, The view just does not seem to recognize the razor engine. I created a strongly type view.

```
@model IEnumerable<RoomsForRent.Domain.Entities.Room>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
```

Yet The model and the viewbag are not recognized. To my surprise, even my Entitiy is showing Unknown element. I am confused. I read about the web.config issue > i checked and tried everything , but mine seem in order and nothing is helping. Below is the web.config from my view folder.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only reliable solution I've ever found to this issue is creating a new project and then moving all your code from your old project into that. Seems to be some bug in VS2013. You can hold out for a better answer and maybe you'll get lucky, but if you want to just move on and get back to work, this will do the trick.

Comment: Well i fixed it by uninstalling VS2013 and installing 2012 express.  2012 works fine. Thank you sir.

Answer (score -2):

If you are having this issue in VS express 2013. Don't waste time, uninstall 20134 and install 2012. Open your project with the newly installed 2012 and you are well to go. The 2013 seems to have a bug.Hope it helps some one.